# Python only finds modules, if called from Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, anaconda

After struggling with this for weeks, I would like to understand the problem. I deinstalled all my python installations and reinstalled Anaconda3 with python 3.7 on windows. When I call python from the anaconda prompt, the imports work flawlessly. But when I double click on the python executable, I get errors importing modules, e.g. with numpy. Therefore my basic question:

What is the difference between the two executions?

When checking sys, I can see that the same executable is called and sys.path is exactly the same. I know many people having the same issues, all of them having had previous installations of python. They are mostly working with Spyder now, but I would like to stick to PyCharm...

Comment: What happens if you open a cmd (regular prompt, not Anaconda Prompt), enter the Python interpreter (by typing `python`) and try to `import numpy`? Also PyCharm is able to hook directly into Anaconda, go into File > Settings > Project Interpreter and select your Anaconda Python interpreter from the drop-down list at the top. Normally the path is `Anaconda3\python.exe`, starting from your Anaconda installation folder. This should allow you to run code from PyCharm using Anaconda's modules, even if you still can't execute code by double-clicking.

Comment: When I start python from regular prompt, I get the same issue. Anaconda prompt seems to add system env variables to make the imports working. It is the issue in https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10714, but I do not feel like setting the environment variables is a good fix. Also I do not understand why it does not work in the first place.

Comment: What PyCharm version do you use? Several conda-related bugs were fixed in 2019.1 and RC is already [available](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/)

Comment: Thanks for the info! I will try it out. Right now I solved it by adding the paths to the environment variable. But I am actually very close to switching to Spyder for good, this has cost me already way too much time.